# Cant Exit Isolation Mode?

Tags: interface

I'm doing Blender Guru's Chair on yt. At one point he isolated a part so we could work on the seams. Now I can't seem to exit the Isolation mode for this part? In Layout Mode it's stuck but in all other modes I can see the parts. I've tried Alt+H and Ctrl+H and 'H' on it's own but nothing seems to change. The outliner shows the parts as visibile.

Any Ideas?

David

Layout Mode - Brace 1 is isolated but other parts are visible in outliner:
[image]

All parts visible in other modes
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called *Local view*.

Switch it on/off through *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*
Shortcut: <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym!!! I knew I was missing something obvious. That was very frustrating.

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your chair.